# SQL insert error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id'

Tags: database, sql-insert

I would like to insert values in my database with this query:

```
INSERT INTO Users (pinConfirmed,Factor,DateUtc,LockoutEnabled,AccessCount,EmailConfirmed)
 values ('false', 'false','1/1/2018' ,'false','0','false')
```

But I get this error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'Users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

But, there are already data in the DB among which Id which is not null.
I checked with these two requests and I have no null for Id.

```
select * from Users where Id IS NULL;
select * from Users where Id = 'NULL';
```

I don't understand where the problem is. 
Need help please.

Comment: What is the table definition?  If `Id` isn't set to produce a value (such as an incrementing integer identity) then it would need a value provided.  You're not providing one, hence the error.

Comment: In fact I copy values ​​from one table to another with an insert into select. There are already values in the field Id. Here is the definition: `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] ([Id] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL  CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);` . I can not do a self increment for values ​​values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comment on the question above, the `Id` column is defined as:

```
[Id] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL
```

And that's it.  No default value, no identity/autoincrement, etc.  Simply a character value which can not be `NULL`.  But when you perform an insert you don't provide a value:

```
INSERT INTO Users (pinConfirmed,Factor,DateUtc,LockoutEnabled,AccessCount,EmailConfirmed)
values ('false', 'false','1/1/2018' ,'false','0','false')
```

That's why you get an error.  `NOT NULL` means a value is *required*.  You're not providing one.

You have a few options:

- Provide a value for the column when you `INSERT`
- Make the column generate its own value (this will depend on your RDBMS, for example in SQL Server you would make the column an `IDENTITY` or in MySQL you'd make it `AUTOINCREMENT`, though both of those are for *integer* columns, whereas yours is *character* data, so you'll need to change the data type as well)
- Allow `NULL`, which of course will only work *once* because this is a primary key column and values must be unique.

Comment: ok David, 
I did an insertion in two times after your explanation I tried to do it in a step and it works. thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

if you go into the table designer, in the properties for the Id column you will see the Identity Specification property set like so:

[image]

Expand that out and set (Is Identity) to Yes. This will set the defaults for Identity Increment and Identity Seed to 1

[image]

Now save the table and you are all set.

Answer (score 0):

ID is the PRIMARY key , it is a unique identifier of the row. It Cannot be left null. That is why you have an error.

Comment: There are values in the column Id.

Comment: @kst92: Not in the data you're trying to insert.  Closely examine your `INSERT` statement.  Where do you see an `Id` value?